# Using Symfony Validation component to validate objects with dynamic properties

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to validate data in an imported csv file with Symfony2's validation component (as of the 2.1 branch) using an external yml ruleset (not in a Symfony project):

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

$builder = Validation::createValidatorBuilder();
$builder->addYamlMapping('rules.yml');

$validator = $builder->getValidator();

$row = (object)array('name' => 'foo');

$violations = $validator->validate($row);
```

This is my yml file:

```
stdClass:
  properties:
    name:
      - MinLength: 10
```

Now there is the problem that it does not seem to be possible with the Validator Component to validate objects with dynamic properties (like the `stdClass` or any other class with magic getters and setters).

When I run that code I get a message saying:

```
[Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\ValidatorException]
Property forename does not exist in class stdClass
```

This is due to the [PropertyMetaclass.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/PropertyMetadata.php#L26) in the highlighted line where the existence is checked by using `property_exists()` which obviously does not work as it's checking against the class and not the object.

Does anyone know how I can get the Validator to work with objects having dynamic properties?

Comment: I updatd the code to show my latest symfony2.1 efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's currently not possible to validate objects with dynamic properties according to this [official statement](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/symfony2/RVxWhs8qcg0/8eVqKbDgr6AJ), so I opened up a [feature request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5420).

My workaround was now to write a very simple code generator class that dumps the class definitions to a file on disc which is then used as class file for the data.

Answer (score 0):

object is not a PHP type.

use stdClass in your yaml file instead of object

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that, had no luck with that, too. I updated the code.

Comment: I now found the problem, it was a stupid error - the yml file was saved as UTF-8 with BOM which did not work. I saved it without BOM and the code continued. But now I'm facing another problem - I updated the post.